# c# EF query explosion

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Dealing with three tables - Company, Employee and User.

Company has 0 or Many Employees.
Employee has a nullable int FK to Company. In practice this alway has a value. 
Employee has a non nullable int FK to User. 
User has a bit field AccountIsDisabled.

In my Data Model I have a partial class extending the EF model class for Company. 
On this the call to ActiveEmployees returning all Employees that are active for the company.

My problem is that this code is generating a query explosion. 
For a company of 1K employees I am getting 1K calls to the DB. It seems EF is creating a call for each employee when navigating to the User table.

I have tried many methods to force eager loading but to no avail.

Anyone out there see a reason that I am getting this query explosion?

```
namespace JCS.Data
{
    public partial class Company : IIdentifiable
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employee> ActiveEmployees
        {
            get
            {
               return Employees.Where(e => !e.User.AccountIsDisabled);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the missing info.

The explosion of queries occurs when a bool property on the related Employee class is accessed. Like so

```
namespace JCS.Data
{
    public partial class Employee : IIdentifiable
    {
        public bool ApprovesTimesheets
        {
            get
            {
                return Company.ActiveEmployees.Any(
                    employee => employee.TimesheetApproverEmployeeID == ID
                            && employee.TimesheetsEnabled);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So anywhere in the code I go

```
bool approvesTimesheets = employee.ApprovesTimesheets;
```

I get the 1K queries.

I have tried adding ToLis() to the Company.ActiveEmployees. No joy.

e.g. 
in Employee class

```
var activeEmployees = Company.ActiveEmployees.ToList();
var approvesTimesheets = activeEmployees .Any(
                      employee => employee.TimesheetApproverEmployeeID == ID
                        && employee.TimesheetsEnabled);
```

the latest in a long line of failed attempts:

```
public List<Employee> ActiveEmployees
    {
        get
        {
            var employees = Employees.AsQueryable().Include(x => x.User).ToList();
            return employees.Where(e => !e.User.AccountIsDisabled).ToList();
            //return Employees.Where(e => !e.User.AccountIsDisabled);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this linq query executes slowly?

Comment: What eager loading did you try?

Comment: Can you show us, how you use `ActiveEmployees` property?

Comment: enumerate the values there with .ToList(), otherwise the query object will be returned (not executed) and then while enumerating it will be executed for each enumerated object

Comment: The question is how do you retrieve that `Company` class from the database, because that's the only place you can apply eager loading.

Comment: Thanks. Please see edits.

Comment: @Ivan can you clarify please? The Company object is accessed in the Employee class

Comment: I meant there must be a place where you create those `Company` objects - like `GetById` or `GelAll()` that return single company or company list. Or something similar where you populate `Employee` objects. Basically the places where you query `dbContext.Companies` or `dbContext.Employees`.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks.....so on initial load I did _currentUser = Repository.Context.Employees.Include("User").Include("Company.Employees.User").FirstOrDefault(e => e.User.Person.Email == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);     seems to have done the trick

Comment: @Creggdev That's exactly what I had in mind! Glad that the issue is solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `.ToList()` or `ToListAsync()` to get all the data at once otherwise it will get the data on the fly per record.

This is the problem with deferred execution VS immediate execution. When you don't materialize the list with `.Where(foo).ToList()` it loads each record whenever you try to access it therefore the 1000 DB calls.

edit: Please note that you are also using a navigational property that points to another object (my guess is that it's object mapped directly to a table ) so, when trying to get that object you also do additional DB calls. to avoid that do something like this :

```
public partial class Company : IIdentifiable
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employee> ActiveEmployees
        {
            get
            {
               return Employees.Where(e => !e.User.AccountIsDisabled).Include(x=>x.User).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not lazy loading (that is, you are not FIXING it by this), but it is the "deferred execution" of LINQ. of course lazy loading bears the same risks, but you would fix it with eager loading (.Include()), not .ToList().

Comment: @MisterPositive The answer? Anyone who works with EF would know that `Employees` is a navigation property (something like `ICollection<Employee>`) which is lazy loaded memory collection, so `ToList` or not `ToList` doesn't really matter. Apparently the OP issue is from lazy loading the `Employee.User` property. And it cannot be fixed in that place of code whatever you do. See my comment on the post.

Comment: Ivan, you are right, i did not notice the navigation property, That should should be with `.Include()`.

Comment: 'EntityCollection<Employee>.Include(bool, bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @Aviatrix that error was from trying your solution.thanks....trying to work it out. So Compay has a related EntityCollection of Employees.

Comment: updated the code, include should go after where, and before to list

Comment: for more details : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

OK the problem stemmed from using navigation properties in the POCOs.

As pointed out by @IvanStoev I could only enforce Eager Loading at the initial call to the DB.

So when I load the initial Employee object I need to load all related objects. So..

```
_currentUser = Repository.Context.Employees.Include("User").Include("Company.Employees.User").FirstOrDefault(e => e.User.Person.Email == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```

Solves the problem. I am worried now that I have a lot of data loaded. Company.Employee is 1K+ object for a big company.

Some more testing needed but the research has greatly increased my understanding of EF. Thanks for the help.